# Tablesorter widgets other than zebra do not work

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

when I use:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({  widgets: [ "zebra"] });
```

widget works perfectly fine with zebra stripes,sortable columns.
but when I use :

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({  widgets: [ "zebra" , "resizable"] });
```

Neither zebra nor resizable widgets work. I used "resizable" scripts you have posted on the tablesorter documentation pages  [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-resizable.html) .

I tried with various jquery versions.Here is what I tried:
`jquery.tablesorter.2.17.1.js` -

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({  widgets: [ "zebra" , "resizable"] });
```

statement works but zebra stripes don't kick in until I sort initially.

`jquery.tablesorter.2.0.5b.js` works fantastic with above statement, but obviously need an updated version for the sake of various widgets.

Comment: are you also using `widgetOptions`? are you asking for help in getting it working, or are you making a bug report (that should probably go [here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues))

Comment: whatever is  [link](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-resizable.html).  But I am not trying to report a bug.   I just want to fix these issues and move on.

Comment: [Resolved](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/639)... next time you have a question, join us on IRC `#tablesorter`